# Scroll to element which is inside the iframe div

Tags: html, jquery, iframe

Hi there i have `iframe` in which there is a `div` and inside div there is one `span`

```
<iframe id="rFrame">
    <div id="resarcbTabBox">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus <span id="highLightYellow">PageMaker</span> including versions of Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
</iframe>
```

The content inside div is huge, but i pasted just small. The iframe is vertically scrollable, what i am trying to do is, i just want to `scroll to the <span> position`.

I am using `jquery.scrollTo.min.js.`

So far i tried various code but no luck, here are some of my effort, but not luck

```
$("#rFrame").scrollTo("#highLightYellow", 10);

$('#rFrame').contents().find('#resarcbTabBox').scrollTo("span#highLightYellow", 10);
```

will anybody put me on right track, what mistake i am making.
Thanks in advance.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vivekSalve/orLvgf8n/2/

Comment: After struggling lot i got solution. $('#rFrame').contents().find('body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#rFrame').contents().find('body').find("#highLightYellow").offset().top
            }, 10);

Comment: may someone find it useful

Comment: You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), instead of adding an answer on the comment. If you want to indicate that a question has an accepted answer, you can click the check/tick mark alongside the answer.

Comment: surely @Shree  i wl do it